# Energy required to remove both electrons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics

The question is:

**Q.** An energy of $24.6$eV is required to remove one of the electrons from a neutral Helium atom. The energy(in eV) required to remove both the electrons from a neutral Helium atom is:

$a.$ 38.2

$b.$ 49.2

$c.$ 51.8

$d.$ 79.0

**My try:** Since after removing an electron the Helium atom becomes a single electron atom, Bohr's Model can be applied. The energy of the single electron is hence given by $-13.6\frac {z^{2}}{n^{2}}$ (where z is atomic no. and n is the no. of the shell in which the electron resides). Thus the energy comes out to be $-13.6\frac {4}{1}$, which is $-54.4$. Thus the total energy required to remove both the electrons is $24.6+54.4=79.0eV$, which should be option $d.$. But the answer is $a.$. Did I go wrong somewhere? Please correct..

Comment: If `a` is correct, then it would appear that `z==n` is true for the single remaining electron.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, can u please elaborate? And why the downvotes?

Comment: Because 24.6 + 13.6 = 38.2.  You were given the 24.6, and the formula $ 13.6 \ast \frac{z^2}{n^2} $ comes out to 13.6 when z==n . PS - I wasn't a downvoter but I'd guess it's 'cause the answer to this is in your textbook :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft why would $Z=n$? Helium has $Z=2$. Where is it said that the remaining electron has $n=2$? If we consider parahelium, then remaining electron should be at $n=1$. Also, look at [this link](http://dept.astro.lsa.umich.edu/~cowley/ionen.htm) where second ionization energy is $54.4eV$

Answer (score 1):

The answer somewhat depends on initial state of the helium atom: orthohelium (total electron spin $S=1$) or parahelium ($S=0$).

If you consider parahelium, which is the lowest energy state, you'll get your d) answer: after removing a single electron another one would be in lowest energy state with $n=1$.

If you consider orthohelium, where electron spins are parallel, or just forget about spin degree of freedom, then by Pauli exclusion principle (and using [atomic shell model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_shell)) second electron might have remained at $n=2$. Then you'd get answer a). But in practice this seems unlikely, because after ionization the remaining electron is likely to go to lowest energy state by mechanism of spontaneous emission; also the higher-excited one would be more likely to become free instead of lower-excited one. So, indeed, this answer should be wrong, and yours right.

Answer (score 0):

My comments were  not intended to provide a solution, just pointing out a condition that must hold if your Bohr Model approach and the provided answer were correct.  Then again, take a look at http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=49775    or
[Energy required for ionizing Helium](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63837/energy-required-for-ionizing-helium) ,

both of which suggest that whoever told you (a) is correct was wrong in the first place.
You could have found this on your own.